# Desktop won't power back up

Tags: 11.10, hibernate

After I tried using the hibernate feature for the first time (to save power/money), now I can't get it to power back on..

I have the latest Ubuntu version, with a home built "Frankenbox" using a 64-bit AMD processor, and never had any problems.

I've tried all the basics: mouse click, keyboard clicks, power button, reset button and then the main power shut off. The lights and fan come on for about 2 seconds, then it shut down again, not long enough to try any of the key combinations.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It seems more like a problem with your machine. It might be because it doesn't have enough power. I had this problem when I connected a powerful video card to my computer and wasn't able to start it normally until I put in a more powerful Power Supply.
I was actually able to power it with the weak Power Supply this way: Try to unplug the cable that goes into your Power Supply(a black cable), leave your PC for ~10-30 minute. I would like to tell you why but I don't know how it is called in English, but basically it has to discharge the electricity while unplugged, and no, pressing the power button while it is unplugged won't help discharge them.

Edit: P.S Sometimes 1 minute is enough too, just leave it for 10 minutes to be sure.

Comment: Are you referring to capacitors?

Comment: @ObsessiveFOSS yes, something like this, it sounds somewhat close to how they are called in my language.